# Cannot ping certain Ubuntu VM servers on separate VLAN

Tags: networking, server, iptables, ping, vmware-workstation

I'm primarily a Windows user and not very experienced working with Ubuntu in general (also kinda new to networks too).
I've been stuck on this for a while and I can't help but feel that I'm missing something really silly.

Cisco RV325 Router

Inter-VLAN routing enabled.

Firewall disabled.

VLAN1: 192.168.20.0/24

- VM1: 192.168.20.8 - Ubuntu 12 testA - no firewall
- VM2: 192.168.20.33 - Ubuntu 12 testB - no firewall
- VM3: 192.168.20.75 - Windows 7
- VM4: 192.168.20.39 - Ubuntu 12 OpenVPN server -no firewall
- PC1: DHCP - Windows 10

VLAN2: 192.168.21.0/24

- PC2: DHCP - Windows 10

Results:

1. PC1 on VLAN1 can ping all VMs on VLAN1
2. PC2 on VLAN2 can ping VM3/4, but not VM1/2, request times out
3. `traceroute` shows that PC2 hits 192.168.20.1 gateway successfully on first hop for all VMs
4. `iptables -L -t nat` shows blank for VM1/2/4

The fact that PC2 can ping VM3/4 makes me think that it's not a problem with the Router nor the VM settings.

I suspected that the Ubuntu Server was not able to route properly and tried changing the following on VM1:

```
> "/etc/network/interfaces"
> 
> iface eth0 inet dhcp   up  route add -net 192.168.21.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.20.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.20.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.21.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

But after restarting I was still not able to ping VM1 from PC2.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: When you added the route for 192.168.21.0/24 to VM1, you basically told VM1 that it was directly connected to ".21".  But it's not directly connected to ".21".  So you'll want to delete that statement.  As for the root issue, there's not enough information here.  maybe you can paste in the ifconfig for each Linux host and the ipconfig for each Windows host so there's more data to review.

Comment: Thanks for the response James, I'll try to grab the information tonight when everyone is offline (running on the old router now so the setup is different).